# How do I get to the chat from the Stack Overflow homepage?

Tags: support

I cannot for the life of me find the link to get to chat. I'm sure there was a little drop down list of things and you could click chat, but I don't know how to get there any more. I only got here because I know the URL. Can someone link me?

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, found it.

It has moved to the right hand side of the screen.

[image: The dropdown]